# How to change the object inspector font?

Tags: delphi, ide

The default font of the object inspector is ridiculously small, esp on a high resolution screen.

Is there a way to make it bigger?

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is and it's really easy.
You can alter any window in the IDE by creating a package and installing this in the IDE.
Because the bpl gets loaded into the main process of the Delphi IDE you can alter any IDE window's properties from there.

[Code by Mike Fletcher](http://delphidabbler.com/tips/224)
Create a new package and add the following unit:

```
unit AdjustOIFont;

interface

uses Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

procedure Register;

implementation

function GetOIForm: TForm;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result:= nil;
  for i:= 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do begin
    if Screen.Forms[i].Name = 'PropertyInspector' then begin
      Result:= Screen.Forms[I];
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetChildControl(AParent: TWinControl; AName: string): TWinControl;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result:= nil;
  for i:= 0 to AParent.ControlCount - 1 do begin
    if AParent.Controls[i].Name = AName then begin
      Result:= TWinControl(AParent.Controls[i]);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetOIControl: TCustomListBox;
var
  OIForm: TForm;
begin
  OIForm:= GetOIForm;
  Result:= TCustomListBox(GetChildControl(GetChildControl(OIForm, 'Panel3'), 'PropList'));
end;

procedure Register;
var
  OI: TListBox;
  OIForm: TForm;
begin
  OIForm:= GetOIForm;
  OIForm.Font.Size:= 10;
  OI:= TListBox(GetOIControl);
  OI.Font.Size:= 10;
  OI.ItemHeight:= 20;
end;

end.
```

Build the package and install.
The change will take effect immediately.

Knowing this trick it's also be easy to collect all the enumerated names in a stringlist and copy them to the clipboard.
These names can than be used to expand the code and fix the fonts of other IDE elements as well (e.g. the Structure pane).

[image]

Much better.

Works on Seattle and XE7.

Comment: The only problem is that the font reverts to small when you select an item in the Object Inspector for editing. If anyone knows a solution for that I'll incorporate it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieving this is by modifying registry like it is described in Malcolm Groves article here: http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1804

Another option is to use `Delphi IDE Colorizer` which is a third party application designed to greatly change appearance of Delphi IDE by changing fonts, colors, etc. You can find it here: https://github.com/RRUZ/Delphi-IDE-Colorizer

And if you perhaps also want to change syntax fonts and syntax highlighting you can also check `Delphi IDE Theme Editor` which is designed to change the appearance of code highlighting based on your desires. You can find it here: https://github.com/RRUZ/delphi-ide-theme-editor

Comment: No, modifying the register does not work. It only changes menu and toolbar font, not the fonts in the floating sub-windows. I did not know the colorizer allows you to change fonts, are you sure? https://github.com/RRUZ/Delphi-IDE-Colorizer/issues/7

Comment: @Johan Actually I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Johan Which version of Delphi do you use?